# How to create an effective Alarm class using the datetime module

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to make a program that will allow for an 'Alarm' class to create certain timers in relation to my timezone using the datetime module.

I have 2 objects from the class to set off at different times but I cannot successfuly delete an instance of the class without receiving an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner Exception in thread Traceback (most recent call last): Traceback (most recent call last): :`

It's fairly clear why it's crashing however I am not sure how efficient my code is in the first place, so my question is: How can I effectively construct an efficient alarm class that will allow for the removal of timers after their execution?

```
class Alarm:
    def __init__(self, timeuntilalarm):
        self.timeuntilalarm = timeuntilalarm
        tdelta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(timeuntilalarm))
        self.alarmtime = real_now + tdelta

    def alarm_check(self):
        if real_now >= self.alarmtime:
            print("has gone off")
            notificationn("Clock App", "Timer is done " + current_hour +
                          ":" + current_minute + "." + current_second + am_or_pm)
            # get rid of that instance
            del(self)

Alarm_Red = Alarm(4)
Alarm_Blue = Alarm(8)

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)
    real_now = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Australia/Brisbane'))
    Alarm_Red.alarm_check()
    Alarm_Blue.alarm_check()
```

Comment: Hello, what error did you got?

Comment: well i get this but then it just repeats:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Thread-3386Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _

Comment: paste it on pastebin.com

Comment: oh well, you dont tell you use threading. idk

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ab2Xwbtj

Comment: As a side-note, we have 2021, Python 3.9 and so you'll want to use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution

```
class Alarm:
    def __init__(self, timeuntilalarm):
        self.timeuntilalarm = timeuntilalarm
        tdelta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(timeuntilalarm))
        self.alarmtime = real_now + tdelta
        self.activated = False

    def alarm_check(self):
        if real_now >= self.alarmtime:
            print("has gone off")
            notificationn("Clock App", "Timer is done " + current_hour +
                          ":" + current_minute + "." + current_second + am_or_pm)
            # get rid of that instance
            self.activated = True

Alarm_Red = Alarm(4)
Alarm_Blue = Alarm(8)

alarms = [Alarm_Red, Alarm_Blue]

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)
    real_now = now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Australia/Brisbane'))
    for i in alarms:
        if i.activated == False:
            i.alarm_check()
```